# Determining the anchor (reference) of a nonrestrictive apposition

Tags: appositives

The following piece is from *Critical Reading Workbook for the SAT 12th Edition (page 23)*:

> The word tephra, from the Greek word meaning ash, has come into use
> among geologists to describe the assortment of fragments, ranging from
> blocks of material to dust, **that is ejected into the air during a
> volcanic eruption**.

I think it is safe to assume that the bold section is a **nonrestrictive apposition** (please correct me if I'm wrong). If that's the case then what is its reference? (the noun that it is renaming)

Comment: Isn't it restrictive, limited to the **assortment of fragments ... ejected into the air during a volcanic eruption"?

Comment: Are you sure that’s an apposition? It would be if “that is” is replaced with “material”, but the bold part as it stands doesn’t look like a noun phrase to me.

Comment: @Lawrence what do you think the bold part is?

Comment: What makes you think it's supplementary (non-restrictive) apposition? It doesn't refer to something ejected into the air, unless it's mentioned in the prior discourse.

Comment: ' . . . the assortment of fragments (blocks of material ... dust) that are . . . ' contains a nonrestrictive appositive (elaborative) within the brackets. I've chosen notional agreement for the quasi-collective/pseudopartitive/quantifier 'assortment [of]'.

Comment: **Restrictive relative clause**: *The word tephra has come into use to describe the assortment **that is ejected into the air**.*

Comment: It's a restrictive relative clause, but bad punctuation gives the wrong impression. Viva voce, there would be no problem. It should be _the assortment of fragments -- ranging from blocks of material to dust -- that is ejected into the air during a volcanic eruption._

Comment: @JohnLawler yeah, I was judging based on the punctuation. Your suggested punctuation is much more sensible.

Comment: So there you have it. It's not an appositive clause but a restrictive relative one that happens to be separated from its antecedent ("assortment of fragments") by the supplementary clause "ranging from blocks of material to dust", Nothing to fret about.

Comment: Punctuation is not a part of grammar, but of typography, which changes without notice.

Comment: I disagree. Punctuation serves to give indications of the grammatical structure (and/or meaning) of stretches of written text, so it **is** part of grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bolded part is a relative clause introduced by the relative pronoun "that", which has for antecedent the noun phrase "assortment of fragments"; it is not a nonrestrictive clause, even if there is a comma before it; this comma is used to set apart the  participial phrase "ranging from blocks to dust", which modifies "assortment of fragments". This postmodification by the -ing clause is itself non-restrictive because it is set between commas. It is not possible to make this non-finite clause restrictive by removing the commas, as then the antecedent of that can be taken to be "dust".

Note Non-restrictive postmodifying  -ing clauses are not found often; those clauses are usually restrictive.

The above deductions can be elicited from COGEL.
**17.34** : **nonrestrictive postmodification by nonfinite clauses**  ex.: The apple tree, *swaying gently in the breeze*, was a reminder of old times.
**17.29** […] postmodifying -ed and -ing participle clauses are both usually restrictive […]

---

From a reading of the comments and answers that followed my answer and from a new reading I can see that something is not right;  if convinced of this,  I still can't say why for sure. The relative clause **is restrictive**, in spite of the comma that precedes it. This would be an exception to the rule.  Nevertheless, I do not think that the punctuation in this sentence is bad.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? *Non-restrictive postmodifying -ing clauses are not found often; those clauses are usually restrictive.*

Comment: I did not know that we can separate a relative clause and its antecedent and put some extra information between the two (_ranging from blocks of material to dust_).

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The clause "ranging from blocks to dust" can't be both non-restrictive _and_ modifying. It's non-restrictive and thus supplementary (non-modifying).

Comment: @TinfoilHat Not much; what I can say  is in an addition  to my answer.

Comment: @BillJ That is not what CoGEL says, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: The commas mark it as a supplement, a non-integrated, non-restrictive adjunct. The Comprehensive is wrong about this.

Comment: @BillJ As usual with user BillJ, it must be taken on faith… Well, grammar is not a religion!

Answer (score 1):

It's a restrictive relative clause. Paring the sentence down:

> The word tephra, from the Greek word meaning ash, has come into use
> among geologists to describe the assortment of fragments, ranging from
> blocks of material to dust, that is ejected into the air during a
> volcanic eruption.

> The word tephra ... has come into use among geologists to describe
> the **assortment** of fragments ... **that** is ejected into the air during a volcanic eruption.

> The word tephra describes the **assortment** of fragments **that** is
> ejected into the air during a volcanic eruption.

It's a specific type of assortment (of fragments) that is restricted to/by the definition in the clause. *That* introduces a restrictive clause; *which* a restrictive or a non-restrictive clause.